# Service Principal Global administrator role for PowerBI Service

Tags: powershell, powerbi, azure-service-principal

Using the service principal account, we would like to run a powershell script that provides us the lineage view of a specific worskpace in json format. To run this, service principal need global admin rights.
We have already provided him with all kinds of rights and we get an unauthorized 401 error. The only person who can run the code is still the global server administrator.

**Is it possible to use the service principal to run such commands that belong to the cmdlet MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt?**

We already use it to get our report list and usage statistics all of these need simple admin user rights and working fine.
Reference post of what we would like to do with code snippets:  https://medium.com/flowe-ita/hacking-power-bi-lineage-which-reports-depends-on-this-table-51b41ccfd0fc